# Compiled Delphi resource can not be read on some Chinese Windows

Tags: windows, delphi, dll, compiler-construction, resources

I have compiled a resource in a dll file in two steps

```
brcc32 Xresource.rc
dcc32 resource.dpr
```

resource.dpr is a delphi project containing

```
library resource;

{$R XResource.res}

begin
end.
```

The problem appears on some (not all) Chinese Windows (XP & 7).  On these machines I can't read the strings from resource.

Any Ideea ? Should I compile it in a different way ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please be more specific about what happens. Is there an error? How do you read the strings from resource?

Comment: Make sure the language in project version information is set to *Neutral* as well as in all resource script files.

Comment: Please mention the delphi version.

Comment: Indeed, I'm guessing it's an older Delphi version because of the manual use of `brcc32`

Comment: @Jerry There are certain use cases for calling brcc32 even in newer Delphi versions - e.g. if you want to add version information or an app icon to your application via external script.

Answer (score 0):

With modern Unicode-ready versions you just keep strings into DFM.

you can also try using resourcestring keyword.